# Sway Animation in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, graphics, core-animation, core-graphics

I was wondering if it's possible to do some sort of sway animation in iOS. For example, a sway animation would be like a store sign blowing in the wind. think westerns. I would like to do this kind of animation when a button is pressed. I'm going for a western kind of feel and that would really put it over the top. Thanks in advance if you know how to do something like this.

Comment: You've now asked 6 question. I think it's time that you take a look at the little check mark beside answers. By clicking this next to the answer that best solved your question, you give the answerer 15 point and a smile, and you earn 2 points and the goodwill of all other users. Go back through those other 5 and see if there aren't worthy answers. That will probably go a long way towards getting more people to address your future questions.

Comment: Alright. Well most answers didnt really answer my question adequetly.

Comment: I figured it out, I did it by setting the anchor point of the button layer to the top middle and then used a 3D rotation.

Comment: You can submit this as an answer and accept it. This way others who come across this post can easily find the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to do this you have to do a couple of things beforehand such as setting the layer anchor point to (0.5,0.0). like the following:

`swaybtn.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);`

And then make a function that gets called when the button is tapped which starts the backwards sway animation, another which sways forward, and a last one that moves back to the original position. The degrees you specify is how far the sway will go and the second number in the rotationAndPerspectiveTransform is the direction the sway will go.
The functions are as follow:

```
-(void)sway:(id)sender{

CGFloat degrees = 50.0;

CALayer *layer;
layer = swaybtn.layer;

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(moveForward)];

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -400;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, degrees * M_PI / 180.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

[UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void)moveForward{

CALayer *layer;
layer = swaybtn.layer;

CGFloat degrees = 50.0;

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"swayforward" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(moveBack)];

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -400;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, degrees * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

[UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void)moveBack{

CALayer *layer;
layer = swaybtn.layer;

CGFloat degrees = 50.0;

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"moveback" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -400;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, degrees * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

And there you go. You should have an animation that sways an object back and forth just like a hanging sign.

Comment: Hi Its great example. Can you help me for Left to Right Sway Animation  insted of Forward -backword sway animation. @Pete42

Comment: It really hard to help you since I do not know what you want it to look like. Do you want it to rotate left a bit and then right? I suggest just setting the anchor point and rotating for that. I would also suggest looking at the CALayer and CATransform3D documentation to get what you really want. I wanted a 3d back and forth so I did it this way. The can also help you with finding out what you want to use https://github.com/honcheng/CATransform3D-Test